# Schema/DTD of PowerPoint

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, openxml

I am looking for a way to add some meta-infromation to PowerPoint files. Specifically, I want to add annotation to bullets and slides.

Are there any XML attributes which can be added to the elements (of the *slideX.xml* file) without invalidating it? In other words, where can I find the schema/DTD of the *slideX.xml* files?

Comment: just wanted to follow up to see if the below answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

"Best Practice" is to download the Open XML SDK 2.0 and use the tool DocumentReflector

Create the document you would like to have and then load that pptx into the DocumentReflector and check how to generate that code....

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/06/announcing-the-first-ctp-of-open-xml-sdk-v2.aspx

*Annotations to slide* is that Notes on the slide?!?! Then you need to create a NotesSlide
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.presentation.notesslide(office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can use `ExtLst` and `Ext` which is basically adding your own extension to PresentationML, to "tag" just about anything at all in SlideX.xml. You can read more about it [here](http://www.documentinteropinitiative.com/implnotes/ECMA-376/P3-8.3.4.1.aspx).

Comment: Hi @Otaku. This seems like a very good answer. Unfortunately, I am currently extremely busy with some other project. When I get back to this issue I will check it more thoroughly. Anyway, thanks a lot. +1

Comment: @Itay: no problem. I'd love to hear the results once you start on this.

Comment: @Itay: just wanted to check in to see if you've had a chance to test this yet.